# Problem with roman/arabic numerals

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I have a problem with abstract numbering. I have this chapter ahead of the table of contents together with the acknowledgements. The toc, list of tables/figures, acknowledgements are all numbered using roman numerals. However, when I get to the abstract the first page is still in roman numerals, the second with a normal number. I'm lost as to why, and how to fix it so any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS Using Texmaker

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.66}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=30mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section] {placeins}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
...

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
Some bollocks I hope my supervisor will believe

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Insertchapternamehere}
\include{Insertchapternamehere}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I made your code into a code block. You need to indent every line by four spaces, not just the first one. The probably easiest way is to mark the code, and press Ctrl+K. And welcome!

Comment: Thanks, I spent a while trying to make the MWE come out correctly but clearly failed.

Comment: Your abstract only consists of one page in the output document. What is that "second page" you're talking about? Also, could you please specify: is switching from roman to arabic numbering from the abstract onwards what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ah sorry, my thesis has a confidentiality agreement on it so I cannot post the contents of the abstract online. Any multiple-page text should reproduce the effect as there's no code, just text in the abstract, other than a single $^{-1}$ math mode and a \textsuperscript\textregistered}

My goal is to have everything up to and including the abstract numbered in roman numerals, and then switch to normal arabic page numbers in the introduction.

Comment: In that case, I think a `\clearpage` at the end of your abstract (just before `\pagenumbering{arabic}` in your code) should do the trick.

Comment: Works!!! That's a stupidly simple solution, bit embarrased I didn't think of that... 

Thanks, that was the very very last bit of editing before submitting nearly 4 years of PhD work!!!

Comment: Good luck on the PhD defense :) Do you mind if we close that question as "too localised"?